# Proof $x$, $1+nx≤ (1+x)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Prof using the binomial theorem: for all integers $n ≥0$ and for all nonnegative real numbers $x$, $1+nx ≤(1+x)^n$.

Don't have a idea to start this one. I don't know how to use math induction yet, so I need a answer without that.

Comment: Expand $(1+x)^n$ by binomial theorem and omit terms you don't need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove by Induction that: $1+nx\le (1+x)^n$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769430/prove-by-induction-that-1nx-le-1xn)

Comment: @choco_addicted  He wants to prove it by binomial theorem.

Comment: just write out $(1+x)^n$ (using the binomial theorem). The first two terms equal $1+nx$, the rest is nonnegative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Binomial theorem :
$$(1+x)^{n} = \sum_{0}^{n}{{{k}\choose{n}}x^{k}} $$
When consider $k=1,k=0$.

Comment: That's just a hint without using math.induction.

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{n}{k}$?

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial theorem:

$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\dots$$

Where $\dots$ is non-negative, as it is a polynomial in $x$ with non-negative coefficients and $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$1=\dbinom{n}{0}1^{n-0}x^0\quad \text{ and } \quad nx=\dbinom{n}{1}1^{n-1}x^1$$

Answer (score 1):

I guess an easy way to do it would be induction if you are having trouble with binomial theorem.
For base case n=1 it is trivial $$1+x \le 1+x$$
Let it be true for some $n=k$. We have
$$\begin{align}
1+kx \le(1+x)^k\\
\Rightarrow (1+kx)(1+x)  \le (1+x)^{k+1}\\
\Rightarrow 1+x(k+1)+kx^2\le(1+x)^{k+1}\\
\end{align}$$
But if $k\gt 0$ and $x\gt0$ we must have
$$\Rightarrow 1+x(k+1)+kx^2 \ge 1+(k+1)x$$
Therefore we have $$1+(k+1)x \le (1+x)^{k+1}$$
Hence by induction $$1+nx \le (1+x)^n$$

Comment: Note your proof works, not on ly for non-negative $x$, but for $x>-1$.